# Android:Error an Exclamation mark in my project how to resolve it

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin

i got a pop up when i started my android eclipse stating that there is a new version which has to be upgraded for 22.6.2 version but your sdk is in 22.3 version even i had error that sdk is not installed in your eclipse so i went to help-> install software added repository then restarted my eclipse.

after that i added my code as usual to start coding my project but i got an exclamatory mark near my project when i compile dialog box appears as you have error in your project

Exclamatory mark shown in image [image]

Next i went to show view -> problems . to check the problems i got an error stating about Android dependencies

[image]

next i went to quick fix the project but dialog box appeared

[image]

after fixing i got an error in jar file itself as shown below

[image]

in this we can check the errors

[image]

i am not able to resolve the error in the jar file can anyone help to resolve it

thanks for your time and help in advance

Comment: You haven't referenced appcompat properly in your project. Do follow http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: i have used the library in libs but also it is coming as ! mark @Raghunandan

Comment: you added it as a jar? If yes that is wrong

Comment: wiat i will post the image of my libs folder check and let me know @Raghunandan as far i am concern i have done how u said

Comment: What have you done? You must reference library project.

Comment: can u see the last image . reference means i didnt get you @Raghunandan

Comment: can u see the last image how my project has become @Raghunandan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference AppCompat.

1. Download the support library under extras from Android sdk Manager.
2. AppCompat is located @ android sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/
3. Import the library project into workspace.

   Select File > Import.
   Select Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next. Browse ( android sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/) and click finish
4. Right click on your project. Goto properties. Android. Add. Browse and Reference AppCOmpat.

Done.

Snaps

Library project imported to eclipse
[image]

Referenced AppCompat
[image]

Comment: it worked for me . my sdk manager was getting corrupted so i couldn't rectify it . now i don't have any errors after adding library file thanks for ur time and encouragement @Raghunandan

Comment: thanks u and I simply got tensed and frustated it is fault in SDk manager

Comment: can i use the localhost/server to populate the images for studio gallery instead of sdcard i have an issue there can i post a new question will u help

Comment: @SandeepV post a different question. yes you can

Answer (score 1):

You can try thus. Such as

You have updated the android sdk but not updated the adt to match with it.

You can update the adt from here

You might need to update the software source for your adt update

Go to eclipse > help > Check for updates.

It should list the latest update of adt. If it is not working try this

go to eclipse > help > Install new software

Click on add

add this url : [update adt dynamically](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)

give it any name.

It will list the updates available- which should ideally be adt 20.xx

Eclipse will restart and hopefully everything should work fine for you.

Comment: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ i want to add this url right to install ADT @omor4android

Comment: then restart eclipse.

Comment: ok i will install and restart the eclipse and let you know @omor4android

Comment: i have added the adt as well but now i cant compile the project because it is invisible @omor4android

Comment: restart your computer. it is better for you, then clean all project.Project=>clean